# How do you append matching cell values into a list?

Tags: python

How do you do add all matching cell values to a list with Pandas?

Excel File Example, Search for Color[Red], append Fruit into `fruit_names = {}`

```
Fruit_ID      Color    Weight   Fruit
1             Red      5lbs     Apple
2             Orange   2lbs     Orange
3             Red      3lbs     Strawberry  


import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir("/users/user/folder/helloworld")
name_list = ["Sheet1"]

fruit_names = {}

def fruit_colors(file):
    data = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = name_list[0])
    for row in data:
            print(format(row[0].value, row[1].value).append(fruit_names))
    print(fruit_names)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.
you can use `df[df['color'] == 'selected color']` to get the fruits you want

you can check it here

[How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

```
fruit_names = []
df = pd.read_excel(file)
red_fruits = df[df['Color'] =='Red']['Fruit'].values
fruit_names.append(red_fruits)
```

Comment: Why am I getting an Index Out of Range error when printing fruit_names[1] but not fruit_names[0]?

It seems everything was grouped into fruit_names[0]?

Comment: by doing `df[df['Color'] =='Red']['Fruit'].values`, you will get a list of values with `color==red`. You can just use `red_fruits` if you're not going to look for other colors